# animate move to the left and to the right?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want is to move my pagination to the left and to the right after clicked on `#prev_pag` and `#next_pag`. how is it and solve my problem?

**Eg:**  http://jsfiddle.net/szVKD/5/

```
$('#next_pag').click(function() {
        $('#pagination').animate({
            left: '-=100px'
        },
        500);
    });
    $('#prev_pag').click(function() {
        $('#pagination').animate({
            left: '+=100px'
        },
        500);
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Needed to delete the last line for javascript to compile and added "position: relative;" to #pagination div.

http://jsfiddle.net/szVKD/9/

Comment: I suggest you use Chrome Browser and then right click on the elements and "Inspect Element" then you'll get a better view of what's happening. Looks like you have a blank space after '2', so the browser is breaking your list (because it thinks its just two big 'words', and it will break the line so it fits the screen, to solve or you remove the space or give space for all elements)

Comment: i use of Chrome Browser and elements in it, but can not problem solving. you can update your example in http://jsfiddle.net/szVKD/9/?

Comment: I'm not sure what exactly is your goal. Can you explain it more clearly?

Comment: please see this eg: http://www.binboy.gigfa.com/admin/accommodation/show => i not want put pagination following each other, i want put are all they in a line.

Comment: this page is not loading here ;/

Answer (score 0):

This is a CSS issue. You need to set `#pagination` to `position:relative;` in order to animate the `left` css property.